# eliminating "not "in the expression using z3

Tags: z3

I try to eliminate "not" in the expression using the script http://rise4fun.com/Z3/XwGt however, it doesn't work, there is still not in the result, would someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The output goals in your example are in simplified formula. There is no redundant assertion in any goal. The Z3 simplified form always use non-strict inequalities such as `t1 <= t2` and `t1 >= t2`. Strict inequalities such as `t1 < 0` are encoded using negation. That is, `t1 < 0` is encoded as `not t1 >= 0`. The idea is to reduce the number of atoms used to encode a big formula.

It would be useful to understand why you need to eliminate the `not`s in the output. If there is an useful application for that, we will include a new tactic (in the next release) that performs the transformation.